# Internal error in Google Play Game Services (11.0.1) in Cloud Save in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I implemented a load/save feature in my game made in Unity 2020.3.26f1 using google play game services- version 11.0.1. Initially it worked, so I haven't changed anything ever since. Right now whenever I call

```
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SavedGame.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution(fileName,DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork,ConflictResolutionStrategy.UseLongestPlaytime,OnSaveGameOpened);
```

the callback status is **Internal Error** without any other information. I checked my google play console and everything seems to be in order. Moreover, user authentication is successful every single time. Has anybody else had a similar issue?